# Django Social Auth giving "Incorrect authentication service" error when trying to login via Twitter

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-apps

I'm sure there aren't too many people on the site that have experience with this but I'm going to get it a shot. I tried installing Django Social Auth for social authentication on a site I am designing but when ever I try logging in using any of the services I get and error that says

```
Incorrect authentication service
```

I am positive that I have the right consumer and secret key inputted and have reinstalled using pip. Should I  try with the just code in the project instead of using the pip version.

Here is my settings.py and local_settings.py combined (couldn't get the code to format correctly on here so I used Pastebin)

```
[http://pastebin.com/7awDzSxX][1]
```

So far I've tried getting the example implementation to work and have failed at that as well. I've been trying to copy as much as possible for it but nothing really seems to work. If you'd like more info about the situation let me know and I can post more code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  incorrect `url` tag parameter. For me works this one

```
    <a href="{% url socialauth_begin 'twitter' %}">Enter using Twitter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to authenticate with Twitter and received the same error. The I realized the twitter backend was commented. It should look like this, obviously applied to whatever backend you're using:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
   'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
)
```